# Facebook Connect Open native facebook App,

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an iPhone app using facebook connection using FBConnect from github code.

It worked fine in the simulator, however when I installed it in the device with existing facebook app from facebook it didn't work. It opens the existing facebook app instead of returning to my own app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this link.

Better you can go with the approach given in the link as it works fine. I have myself tried this code and it has worked for me.

Also the sample project (with Facebook API implemented in it) is given in the below link which will be helpful for you to while implementing the facebook API as per the method given in the below link.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Also you can test the sample project on your device before going for this approach

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: I used this api But problem with this appi We can't get the method on cancel click or close

Comment: @GhostRider: Which method are you talking about? I am not clear about that.

Comment: @Parth :i want to know about cancel the web view

Comment: @GhostRider: It has a close button below if I am not wrong. There is a close button below the webview which dismisses the modal view

Comment: @GhostRider: I have edited my answer and added the screenshot about the webView and close button below it. I hope this is what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered a URL handler to respond to return requests from the Facebook app? on iOS 4 the Facebook SDK uses fast app switching which is designed to let the app handle most of the heavy lifting and let the users just hit "Accept" instead of having to re-enter login/passwords